# Arduino: How to eliminate thermocouple amplier noise

Tags: filter, arduino, noise

**Scenario:** 
 
I m experimenting the thermocouple amplifier (SN-6675) with Arduino DUE.
After i'm included MAX6675 library, Arduino can measured room temperature.
However, Temp measured from  arduino have 2 issues,

1) offset compare to "Fluke thermometer"
2) have tons of noise, and keep fluctuated after taking average of each 5 temperature sample.

eg, Fluke thermometer got 28.9C at room temp, arduino got 19.75~45.75C

**Question:** Any method/filter to reduce the measured noise, and gives a steady output?

[image]

Codes is attached for reference.

```
#include <MAX6675.h>

//TCamp Int
int CS = 7;              // CS pin on MAX6675
int SO = 8;              // SO pin of MAX6675
int SCKpin = 6;             // SCK pin of MAX6675
int units = 1;            // Units to readout temp (0 = ˚F, 1 = ˚C)
float error = 0.0;        // Temperature compensation error
float tmp = 0.0;  // Temperature output variable

//checking
int no = 0;

MAX6675 temp0(CS,SO,SCKpin,units,error); // Initialize the MAX6675 Library for our chip

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
}

void loop() {

  no= no + 1;
  tmp = temp0.read_temp(5); // Read the temp 5 times and return the average value to the var

  Serial.print(tmp);
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(no);

  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: With that much variability on an average of 5 readings, you surely have an electrical problem.  There isn't much you can troubleshoot.  Check the thermocouple for a bad connection or broken weld.  More likely is power supply noise.  5V supplies can be very noise.  Adding some filtering to the Vcc may improve.  Ask on Arduino stack exchange for hardware related issues.

Answer (score 1):

> Any method/filter to reduce the measured noise, and gives a steady output?

The [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is pretty much *the* standard method for this:

> Kalman filtering, also known as linear quadratic estimation (LQE), is an algorithm that uses a series of measurements observed over time, containing noise (random variations) and other inaccuracies, and produces estimates of unknown variables that tend to be more precise than those based on a single measurement alone.

If your background isn't maths, don't be put off by the formulas that you come across. In the single-variable case like yours, the filter is remarkably easy to implement, and I am sure googling will find a few implementations.

The filter will give you an estimate of the temperature as well an estimate of the *variance* of the temperature (the latter gives you an idea about how confident the filter is about its current estimate).

Comment: Kalman filtering is complete overkill for a problem as simple as this one and it requires that you know the properties of your noise and have a physical model of your system. I guess it does not give you anything more than what can be achieved with a simple moving average or [decay averaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) and tuning the averaging time by hand. But as mentioned by the other comment, I would check electrical connections first.

Comment: @BasSwinckels: What you are proposing ([EWMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing)) is equivalent to what I am proposing ([Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)), as discussed in some detail in [Durbin and Koopman](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0198523548). See [What is the difference between Kalman filter and moving average?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16458/what-is-the-difference-between-kalman-filter-and-moving-average)

Comment: For a simple thermal system, the end result might be the same. I just wouldn't scare a beginner with Kalman filters. I know about state estimators and have done a fair bit of quick and dirty signal analysis of experimental systems, but have so far found Kalman filters too complicated for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to go for a simpler **averaging** algorithm. This is not as elegant as a low pass algorithm but may be adequate for your case. *These algorithms are plentiful on the web*.

You can monkey around with the number of samples you take to balance the compromise between latency and stability. You may want to start with 10 samples and work from there.